# Javascript client side in sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am new to sharepoint 2013 and I have a requirement to achieve a customized Icon overlay image for a doc library. The iconoverlay image shd be replaced only if the  column  'Complete' has a value yes. No access to server side , have access only to site.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite understand your question but if you want to change the default list view of a document library. You can consider using JSLink which is part of SP2013 new feature.

The idea is to inject a JS into your Document List View Web Part and do some UI changes.

I'm attaching a sample of checking the item "Completed" column and modify the Column "Name" to have Bold effect.

```
(function () { 

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var NameFiledContext = {}; 
    NameFiledContext.Templates = {}; 
    NameFiledContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View 
        "LinkFilename": { "View": LinkFilenameFiledTemplate } 
    }; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(NameFiledContext); 

})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
function LinkFilenameFiledTemplate(ctx) { 

    var completedColumn = "Completed";
    var link = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.RealFieldName];
    var completed = ctx.CurrentItem[completedColumn];
 console.log(link);
    // Return html element with appropriate color based on priority value 
    if(completed){
        return "<strong>" + link + "</strong>";
    } 
    return link;
}
```

Create a JS and copy the above code, save it somewhere into your SharePoint.
Go to the Document Library that you want to modify, Edit the Page, Edit the Web Part property, go to the "Misc" section of web part property panel and include "~sitecollection/xxxx link to the JS" into the JSLINK field.